# JSON parsing error with erb on Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, syntax-error

I'm trying to be able to have acess to a `JSON` file in a script tag in a `.erb` file which is a view for my Rails project.

I have this in my controller:

```
@myJSON = JSON(IO.binread("./path/to/file.json"));
```

And I have tried this in the view file:

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
    var thing = <%= @myJSON %>;
<% end %>
```

But it gives me a SyntaxError in the console `SyntaxError: expected property name, got '&'`, which is pretty obvious because the output in the code is something like:

```
var thing = [{&quot;sigla&quot;=&gt;&quot;AC&quot;, &quot;nome&quot;=&gt;&quot;Acre&quot;, &quot;cidades&quot;=&gt;[&quot;Rio Branco&quot;, ...]}]
```

What am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in `javascript_tag`:

```
var thing = <%= @myJSON.to_json.html_safe %>;
```